# Possible to restore Appkit after Catalina→Monterey Update?

Tags: macos, applications, catalina, monterey

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me, but I'm aware it might be a long-shot.

I've come to rely on an app called [Auganizer](http://www.auganizer.com) which has been completely abandoned by its developers.

After upgrading from Catalina to Monterey, I get the following error when trying to launch it:

```
Termination Reason:    Namespace DYLD, Code 4 Symbol missing
Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSActionCell._tag
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Auganizer.app/Contents/MacOS/Auganizer
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
```

There is no *Appkit* at all in `/System/Library/Frameworks/`, but there *is* one in the equivalent directory of the Time Machine backup of my Catalina system.

Is there any way to restore this file or some other way to fix the missing symbol error?

Comment: You may need to add a Catalina virtual machine on your Mac to run it. In there site it is just said that it can run up to Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure that would work because the app organises Logic Pro component plugins into categories, so I think it has to be installed on the same system as Logic / the plugins.

Someone else had a couple of suggestions:

"1) Manually copy the missing appkit files to the location where it is expected.
2) Using command line tools to change where Auganizer should look for the missing libraries."

The first option involves editing the frameworks folder, which makes me nervous. The second is beyond my capability as I have no coding experience.

Comment: Another way is to use docker but I never did it on Mac. This prevent to run virtual machine and lay enable to see the already existing plugins directories.

Comment: You can also try to start from another volume with Catalina version when you need to use auganizer

Comment: @PtitXav, unfortunately I don't think any of those options would be possible. Auganizer doesn't let you specify the plugin folder to 'auganize', which precludes installing it on any volume other than the one your plugins are installed on. 

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Auganizer binary is linked to Appkit by the hardcoded path, and when Monterey moved Appkit into dylib shared cache it became unavailable for the apps, which are trying to find it by the file system path. So in order to make it work it will be necessary to modify the import section of Auganizer and its libs to make it use Appkit from dylib shared cache.

So you'll have the hacked binaries with the broken digital signtures. Also even if you change the paths there, you may stumble into some symbol which was deprecated and no longer exist in Monterey version of AppKit, so it will be necessary to find the analog.

To mee it doesn't look reasonable to spent so much time on reviving the 35$ software.

Comment: thanks for the info. Since posting this question, I've reverted to using Logic's own plugin organiser in combination with some Keyboard Maestro macros that fill in the gaps. The main one is not knowing which plugins are yet to be categorised.

For anyone interested, here is the macro:

https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/logic-pro-plugin-category-report/30670